# Existence and Uniqueness theorem - doubts

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The class material presents the Existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs as follows
[image]
[image]

What I don't understand is the meaning of $r$. I understand that the solution lies within a subinterval of $(t_0 - a, t_0 + a)$, specifically $(t_0 - r, t_0 + r)$, but what exactly does $r$ represent? And what is the significance of $b/M$? How does the inequality $r \leq b/M$ ensure that the solution $x(t)$ will remain within the rectangle?

Comment: $r$ gives you a lower bound for the existence time of the solution of your equation.

Comment: @JonasLenz right, but what's the meaning of $b/M$, where $M$ seems to be the highest slope of the tangent to the graph

Comment: Not sure what you mean by meaning

Comment: Why can $r$ be equal to $b/M$? How does it serve as a lower bound for the existence time of the solution? I also don't get the meaning of $M$ in this context. I mean, why $b/M$ ensures that the solution stays inside the rectangle?

Comment: Was there a prove presented in your course?

Comment: I only have the slides, and that's what they say

Comment: See the proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean, why $b/M$ ensures that the solution stays inside the rectangle?

Hint: **if** the solution exists:
$$\dot x(t) = F(t,x(t))\implies |\dot x(t)|\le M \implies -M\le\dot x(t)\le M.$$
Integrating:
$$-M(t - t_0)\le x(t) - x(t_0)\le M(t - t_0).$$
Can you continue?

Comment: I'm sorry for the naive question, but how do you get the second row by integrating? Can you kindly complete the answer?

Comment: @Maximilian, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.